# Multirow vertical size of graphic

Tags: graphics, multirow

I know that combining `multirow` with graphics isn't intended. `multirow` cannot calculate the height of the graphic and it overflows.

Here's the minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular} {|c|c|c|}
\hline 
\textsf{\textbf{Development Phase}} & \textsf{\textbf{Integration Step}} & \textsf{\textbf{Test Stage Home News Blas}} \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Hardware Development} & \multirow{2}{*}{ \includegraphics[height=100px]{universe.jpg} } & \textsf{\footnotesize Hardware Test} \\
\cline{3-3}
 &  & {\footnotesize HW-SW Integration Test } \\
\hline

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Is there an alternative package for `multirow`, or a workaround?

The solutions I have found by searching, are not useful for me. I don't want to change the size of the non-`multirow` cells!

Or is there a option for the height of the `multirow` (I couldn't find one in the documentation)?

Comment: Avoid the tabu package. It is broken and unmaintained. See the readme here https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu/.  I don't investigate questions where tabu is a relevant part.

Comment: It's not related to tabu.

Comment: then why does you example uses tabu?

Comment: Because tabu works for me and I convieniently used my code. I've edited my code. As I said it's a multirow x graphics problem......

Comment: it is rather unclear what layout you want. If you don't want to change the size of the other rows where should the height of graphicx go?

Answer (score 1):

like this?

[image]

Sum of heights of the spanned rows should be equal to image height. Tis you can achieve with add `rule` with adequate height:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}  % load graphicx too
%\usepackage{tabu}              % not recommended, it is bugy
\usepackage{longtable, multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular} {|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textsf{\textbf{Development Phase}} & \textsf{\textbf{Integration Step}} & \textsf{\textbf{Test Stage Home News Blas}} \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Hardware Development} 
    & \multirow{2}{*}{\includegraphics[height=100px, 
                                       margin=0pt 3pt 0pt 3pt]{example-image-duck} }
        & \textsf{\footnotesize Hardware Test}\rule[-43px]{0pt}{50px} \\
\cline{3-3}
    &   & {\footnotesize HW-SW Integration Test}\rule[-43px]{0pt}{50px} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

**Addendum (1):**
One way is not use of `multirow` cells and devide last cel into two parts by use `makecell`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}  % load graphicx too
%\usepackage{tabu}              % not recommended, it is bugy
\usepackage{longtable, makecell, multirow}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries\sffamily}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{3pt}


\begin{document}

\begingroup
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|>{\footnotesize}c|}
    \hline
\thead{Development Phase}
    &   \thead{Integration Step} 
        &   \thead{Test Stage Home News Blas}                   \\
    \hline
Hardware Development
    &   \includegraphics[height=100px,
                         valign=t]{example-image-duck} 
        &   \makecell[t]{\sffamily Hardware Test   \\[5ex]
                            \hline\\ 
                         HW-SW Integration Test} \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum (2):**
Today I would use  `tabularay` package with option `vspan=even` and width equal to `\textwidth` (due to use of the  `X` columns type):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}  % load graphicx too
\usepackage{tabularray}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {Q[l,h] X[c] X[l, h]},
              colsep = 3pt,
              rowsep = 3pt,
              row{1} = {font=\small\bfseries, c},
              vspan=even    % <---
             }
Development Phase
    &   Integration Step 
        &   Test Stage Home News Blas   \\
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    Hardware Development
    &   \SetCell[r=2]{c}    \includegraphics[valign=t]{example-image-duck}
        &   Hardware Test               \\  
    &   &   HW-SW Integration Test      \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is how I want the table to look like. The solution is not suitable for me. I have a lot of those and I don't want to stretch the non-multirow cells. I want to give the multirow cell the height of the graphic.

Comment: @Moone, what you like to have is not possible with `multirow` Also not exist any packages which will do this for you. Another possibilities, is not use two rows in the last column and adequately reformat this cell contents.